# Vim - поисковой запрос

Tags: linux, vim

Добрый вечер! Не получается составить поисковой запрос для вима, для упрощения прыгания между частями кода.

Запрос должен находить строки удовлетворяющие любому из условий:

1) Содержит в себе открывающую фигурную скобку {

2) Является пустой линией

Информация которую нашел

- нашел что пустые линии ищутся так:/^$
- а скобки так /{
- объединение запроса \|

По отдельности все работает, но когда я пытаюсь соединить в конструкцию, ищутся только скобки
Пробовал вот так -/^$\|{

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Приведите пример кода. Если нужно перемещатся по блокам с кодом в vim есть } и { в основном режиме.

Comment: :set list покажет все не печатывемые символы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указанная Вами конструкция является **верной**.

Я уверен что проблема в самих "Пустых строках". Либо там пробелы, либо знаки табуляции.
Также, не исключено что там не-unix окончания строк.

Чуть не забыл. Для вашей ситуации больше подойдёт такое выражение:
/^$\|^[[:space:]]\|^\t\|{

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Похоже что проблема в том что я использую не vim, а плагин эмулирующий его в одной из популярных IDE. Завел issue разработчику на гитхабе.